# I have a USB drive formatted as FAT32. How can I set its permissions in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: linux, usb, fat32

I can read the files but can't write or change the permissions of a file I wanted.

Comment: Since FAT32 doesn't have permissions built in, the drive is probably mounted readonly. Check with the `mount` command.

Answer (score 0):

Since FAT32 doesn't have permissions built in, the drive is probably mounted readonly. Check with the mount command.